# Autocorrect in combobox

Tags: ms-access

**Edit**: I have one column in the table. For example its call "Title". This column has a combobox that has list of items like "Best In Show", "Best In Group" etc. I want to select one of the following drop-down list of items was a different text. For example: I have selected "Best In Show" but in column its should looks like "BIS!"

Of course that other text that will replace the original in the drop-down list is also known that I can post in SQL-query or in macros or in other tables or elsewhere

Let me know if you need more info. Thanks.

Comment: Please add more information to the question, maybe some screen shots of what you have got/would like. Also try re-wording your question as best you can as currently it is rather difficult to understand what it is you are attempting to describe.

Comment: The row source of your combo box: Is it a table? Is it a list of values?

Answer (score 1):

Use as the record source for the combo a table/query/value list with two columns, the first with the abbreviation, the second with the display value.

Set the number of columns in the combo to 2, and set the Column Width of the first column to 0.

This will then show the display value for the actual value in the database.

Comment: Actually this is the same answer as mine, and I think it's good for what Maxim wants.

Answer (score 0):

Also see the last answer [MS Access Dropdown List/Combo Box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/602794/ms-access-dropdown-list-combo-box)

Comment: I'm sorry, but how WPF can help me in MS Access? But you understood my problem correctly

Comment: The point here is that you want three columns in a precise order, to show what you want to see in the control.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have a Film (ID, Title, Abbrv) table and a Person (ID, Name) table.

And you also have a union table Person_Film (PersonID, FilmID)

For the union table, Person_Film, you'd like to select a person based on his/her name, and a film based on its title, but you'd like to see the abbreviation instead.

What you do is to use the Lookup wizard on your Person_Film.FilmID field. You do so by choosing "Lookup wizard..." instead of a data type when in design view for the forementioned table and field and choosing the first option, "I want the lookup column to look up the values in a table or query"

If the wizard complains saying that there exist a relationship based on that field, just go to the Relations screen in the Tools menu, delete the relation (look for the field in the table) and retry. Don't worry: The wizard will re-create the relation in the end.

[image: Lookup wizard]

You select the Film table as row source, and select ID, Abbrv and Title (in that order). Leave the option to hide the key column checked, as recommended.

The result is something like this:

[image]

Comment: Using the Lookup Wizzard has the same effect as manually change the settings in the Lookup tab for the field in design view as proposed in Monty Wild's answer.