# MS Access - Store drop-down list items as other values in the table

Tags: ms-access, drop-down-menu

This is my very first time using MS Access. I am using the 2013 version.

What I want to do is essentially create a field in my table that acts as an "enum": it should be a drop-down list that, when viewed in the form, should display items as strings, but when saved to the table should be seen as integers.

For example: if my "enum" is "Apple - 0; Orange - 1; Banana - 2", I would like the form to display a drop-down list with items "Apple", "Orange" and "Banana", while saving whatever the user chooses as either "0", "1" or "2" in the corresponding table entry.

I have found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/602794/ms-access-dropdown-list-combo-box) that asks something similar, but this seems to be for situations where you populate your drop-down list with entries from other tables. I, however, would just need my list populated with my static enum. I am not experienced enough to apply the answers in there to my situation.

When I create my drop-down list field in the table, I can choose to enter my values manually, and I can then create more than 1 column of items. I suspect what I want to achieve has something to do with this, but when I enter my strings in the first column and my corresponding integers in the second, both columns are visible in the form and in the table entry (i.e. I see "Apple | 0", "Orange | 1" and "Banana | 2" as the drop-down list items).

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What's wrong with creating a table with 2 fields, `ID` and `Fruit`? `ID` can be the integer field (1, 2, or 3) and `Fruit` can be a text field that holds `Apple, Orange, and Banana. When showing this tables' values in the dropdown, you can choose to hide the `ID` column. This will perform exactly the way you are requesting.

Comment: I guess it would be possible to do it this way; however, I forgot to mention that I have many different enums to implement. I don't know if I like the idea of having 20-25 tables in the database just to save the static enum values. Is there no way to do it directly in the field / drop-down list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get it working the way I wanted to. When creating the drop-down list field in the table, choose to enter your own values, and then create 2 columns. Use the first column to enter your integers, and the second column to enter your values. For some reason I had always tried putting my integers in the second column, and it wasn't giving the correct result. Once your field is created, go to your form and edit the properties of the drop-down list to hide the first column (Column widths: 0cm;1cm).

You now have text only in your form drop-down list, and integers only in your table field.